# I need to extract text from xml using lxml

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, lxml

Here, XML is `xml='''<root>He<b>l<i>l</i>o</b>, <i>wo<b>r</b>ld!</i></root>'''`.

It should print "Hello, world!"

I am using Python lxml library to get the text but it does not print accurately as the expected string.
If you have a better idea to get the text out of the XML, it will be helpful.

Comment: Can you please post the code you've written and what is the problem with expected and actual outputs?

Comment: You can try BeautifulSoup, but as @Colwin pointed out, there is not enough info to give advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
from lxml import html

xml_data = '''<root>He<b>l<i>l</i>o</b>, <i>wo<b>r</b>ld!</i></root>'''
tree = html.fromstring(xml_data)
print ''.join(tree.xpath('//text()'))
```

> **Note:** Double slash (//) is the descendant-or-self axis; it is short for /descendant-or-self::node()/

Comment: Thank you answering @andres,But I need to extract text without using xpath.

Comment: @sunnysingh you mentioned you were using lxml, that's why I posted this answer

Comment: Yeah,its true But I have to solve without inbuilt function of lxml.

Comment: @sunnysingh: WHY can't you use xpath? WHY didn't you say so in the question?

Comment: yeah,It was my mistake and don't worry i am going to approve your answer and hope you do the same